# Confusion between clamscan and clamdscan

Tags: 14.04, clamav

If i am running `clamscan -v` under clamav-0.99.1 package, it is showing

```
----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 4297948
Engine version: 0.99.1
Scanned directories: 1
Scanned files: 39
Infected files: 0
Data scanned: 5.25 MB
Data read: 2.37 MB (ratio 2.22:1)
Time: 6.649 sec (0 m 6 s)
```

If i am running `clamdscan -v` under clamav-0.99.1 package, it is showing

```
----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Infected files: 52
Time: 1.936 sec (0 m 1 s)
```

If i run particularly under clamav-0.99.1/test directory, `clamscan -v`, it is showing

```
----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 4297948
Engine version: 0.99.1
Scanned directories: 1
Scanned files: 52
Infected files: 48
Data scanned: 14.52 MB
Data read: 6.94 MB (ratio 2.09:1)
Time: 8.117 sec (0 m 8 s)
```

And in `clamdscan -v`, it is showing

```
----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Infected files: 52
Time: 1.184 sec (0 m 1 s)
```

Why is this difference?? Does running from super directory and particular directory matters??

Why `clamscan -v` is showing

```
Scanned files: 52
Infected files: 48
```

while `clamdscan -v` always showing

```
Infected files: 52
```

??

Comment: As far as I know clamdscan works like as a replacement of clamscan.You should not be worried about it .It does not matter actually what directory it is. If you ask people which one they use I would say clamscan.

Comment: One of most important thing is that clamdscan ignores most of the command line  options of clamscan, therefore I doubt that it does not do an accurate scan.This is why, I would conclude you see an untrustful output from clamdscan in your result.

Comment: any solution by now ? It still works same ?

Answer (score 2):

`clamdscan` is configured in `/etc/clamav/clamd.conf`. It allows faster scan by using parallelization with `--multiscan` which is using more resources, of course.